# Linux bridge static IP using only one NIC

Tags: linux, routing, bridge

It seems like I have a generic problem, but can't find any solution - every solution that I found so far on internets doesn't work for me. Let me first try to explain what I am trying to do - I have a linux box with three interfaces - one is uplink going to provider and two others are supposed to be two physical parts of a single logical network. So I have the following:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1488
    inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 10.255.255.255
    ether 00:24:9b:04:3b:a7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 102156  bytes 8545914 (8.1 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 44194  bytes 7959306 (7.5 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
eth1: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1488
    ether 00:24:9b:04:3f:ae  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 56553  bytes 4992101 (4.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 15920  bytes 4418268 (4.2 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
eth2: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1488
    ether 00:24:9b:04:3b:a7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 56298  bytes 7582661 (7.2 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 64175  bytes 8148316 (7.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

br0 is bridging eth1 and eth2 and also is supposed to have a static address used as a gateway. Now here is the problem - if I am on gateway and I try to ping a box in segment attached to eth2 - everything works - arp is resolved and icmp flows, but if I am trying to ping something in eth1 segment - I see arp requests on eth2 and obviously nothing happens.

So in general my problem is that bridge is using only ONE MAC address - the one that eth2 has. Any pointers to documentation that I might have missed or suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

Additional information as requested:

```
# ip r sh
default dev ppp0  scope link
10.0.0.0/8 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1
192.168.101.115 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.6.59

# ip link sh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
link/ether da:f3:53:e3:69:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: tunl0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT
link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1488 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
link/ether 00:24:9b:04:3f:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1488 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
link/ether 00:24:9b:04:3b:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1488 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT
link/ether 00:24:9b:04:3b:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 3
link/ppp

# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.00249b043ba7       no              eth1
                                                    eth2
```

Ok, a short update depending on the order of ifconfig/brctl addif - I can make it send packets either via eth1 or via eth2.

Comment: It is supposed to use only one mac. Please post the output of `ip r sh`, `ip link sh` and `brctl show`.

Comment: added to original post

Comment: That looks quite sane. Are there, by any means, "special" component in that server's environment which could somehow create a bridging loop? I've noted that MTU is 1488. Can it be related? Also `dmesg` could have interesting messages about the interfaces/bridge. Though I can't think of a single thing which would stop the arp request going out all the interfaces: it's broadcast traffic and should be flooded on all the UP ports (you have stp disabled so no forwarding/blocked state to consider).

Comment: The only special thing I can think of is that eth1/eth2 are USB cards, that is the only "special" thing about the system - nothing wireless or anything - just plain USB ethernet cards. `dmesg` doesn't have much:[   15.060000] br0: port 2(eth2) entering forwarding state
[   15.070000] br0: port 2(eth2) entering forwarding state
[   15.070000] br0: port 1(eth1) entering forwarding state
[   15.080000] br0: port 1(eth1) entering forwarding state
` Interesting to mention is that if I remove eth2 from bridge and only eth1 is left then eth1 is selected...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about USB NICs, but it's common for WLAN cards to drop any outgoing frames with a source MAC which isn't theirs.

Your broadcasted ARP request may be leaving br0 with source MAC `a7`. eth2 also happens to have MAC `a7` so it forwards the frame, however eth1 has MAC `ae` so it drops the frame.

You could confirm this by changing the MAC of the bridge manually (`ip link set dev br0 address <MAC>`), first to the `ae` MAC and seeing if your "working" interface switches from eth2 to eth1, then to some new random MAC and seeing if neither interface forwards traffic.

Comment: This is not exactly a case if I change MAC not to belong to either interface I still see packets going out from eth2: `[root@daemonhouse ~]# tcpdump -X -vvv -ni eth2 host 10.0.1.101
tcpdump: WARNING: eth2: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
19:58:17.421134 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.0.1.101 tell 10.0.0.1, length 28
        0x0000:  0001 0800 0604 0001 0024 cafe babe 0a00  .........$......
        0x0010:  0001 0000 0000 0000 0a00 0165            ...........e
` - mac is set to 00:24:ca:fe:ba:be